# Netboot OS X installation from an Ubuntu Linux system

Tags: linux, mac-osx, netboot

I'm interested in netbooting an OS X install (Snow Leopard) from my Ubuntu box. I've made an ISO of the install dvd, but I'm not sure how to proceed from here. I know it's possible to do this from an OS X server, but can it be done from Linux as well?

The Macs that need to receive the netinstall are all intel versions.

Comment: I'm not sure why there's a vote to move this to superuser - netboot is a systems admin thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never tried it myself - I do netboot from OSX server because its nice and easy - but there is a guide to doing this available at afp548.com, [here](https://www.afp548.com/2006/12/20/howto-configure-gnulinux-to-provide-bsdp-netboot-services/). The example talks about CentOS but I guess you can either adapt the steps to work with Ubuntu or install CentOS on another box.

Comment: An anonymous user noted that your link has died. :(

Comment: Thanks @HopelessN00b - updated link to another guide I know.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an (admittedly old) article about making any Mac a Netboot server: http://www.macgeekery.com/hacks/hardware/make_any_mac_a_netboot_server

The author does say the idea of a Linux based netboot server is probably possible:

> And for good measure, I’ll show you how to do this without having to use BSDP at all (Debian NetBoot server, anyone?).

But I can't find any info on that ever having been accomplished.